# PHP Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:/xampp/htdocs/oops/1.php on line 9?

Tags: php, oop

I need to assign b value in a inside the method onec, but its failing. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here:

```
<?php

class One {

    public $a = 10;
    public $b = 20;

    public static function onec() {
        $this->a = $this->b;
        return $this->a;
    }

}

echo One::onec();

?>
```

Comment: Have a look at this [PHP Static Methods & Properties](http://phpduck.com/php-static-methods-and-properties/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `self` keyword. The `$this` keyword is not accessible under static context. Also, you should make your variables `static`

Like this..

```
<?php

class One {

    public static $a = 10;
    public static $b = 20;

    public static function onec() {
        self::$a = self::$b;
        return self::$a;
    }

}
echo One::onec();
```

Answer (score 0):

You use $this in static function. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

```
<?php

class One {

    public $a = 10;
    public $b = 20;

    public static function onec() {
        $obj = new One();
        $obj->a = $obj->b;
        return $obj->a;
    }

}

echo One::onec();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
class One {
   public $a = 10;
   public $b = 20;

   public function onec() {
     $this->a = $this->b;
     return $this->a;
   }
}
$obj = new One();
echo $obj->onec();
```